# Splitting a string with multiple white spaces with perl?

Tags: regex, perl, split

I am trying to split a string with multiple white spaces. I only want to split where there are 2 or more white spaces. I have tried multiple things and I keep getting the same output which is that it splits after every letter. Here is the last thing I tried

```
@cellMessage = split(s/ {2,}//g, $message);
                foreach(@cellMessage){
                    print "$_ \n";
                }
```

Comment: Tag this question with the language that you use and you'll get more responses.

Comment: Yeah ...  I don't know Perl, but this looks like Perl to me.  Probably a typo, then.  ;P

Comment: It's been alluded to, but no one's quite spelled it out for you yet: `s/ {2,}//g` is a substitution operation on the default variable `$_`, and doesn't yield a regex for `split` to use. All it returns is a number signifying how many substitutions occurred on whatever's in `$_`. Refer here for how that operator works: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
@cellMessage = split(/ {2,}/, $message);
```

Comment: But it is not really whitespace, only spaces. \s will also give you tabs:

@cellMessage = split(/\s{2,}/, $message);

Comment: Another small refinement would be to use + instead of {2,}. The + means exactly that, "at least one of": split(/\s+/, $message);

Comment: @Philippe A., he said he wanted to split on 2 or more spaces.  That would be `/\s\s+/`, which is only 1 less character than `/\s{2,}/`.  They both mean the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

Keeping the syntax you used in your example I would recommend this:

```
@cellMessage = split(/\s{2,}/, $message);
                foreach(@cellMessage){
                    print "$_ \n";
                }
```

because you will match any whitespace character (tabs, spaces, etc...). The problem with your original code was that the `split` instruction is looking for a pattern and the regex you provided was resulting in the empty string `//`, which splits `$message` into individual characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

#                  1    22     333
my $message = 'this that  other   555';
my @cellMessage = split /\s{2,}/, $message;
print Dumper(\@cellMessage);

__END__

$VAR1 = [
          'this that',
          'other',
          '555'
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do:

@cellMessage = split(/\s+/, $message);

It does the same thing as " @cellMessage = split(/ {2,}/, $message);" but looks a little cleaner to me imo.

Comment: nevermind, misread the question. bad answer here, it only works for 1 or more spaces

Answer (score -1):

Try this one: `\b(\s{2,})\b`

That should get you anything with multiple spaces between word boundries.

Comment: Shinjuo's split syntax was wrong. It has nothing to do with word boundaries. Erik has the right answer.