# how would I trim and split into perl hash

Tags: perl, hash, split

I have this string

```
$st="station_1:50, station_2:40, station_3:60";
```

how would I split this into a Perl hash table ?

I try

```
%hash = map{split /\:/, $_}(split /, /, $st);
```

it does correctly - but what if there is n-space between the , and station?
how would I make it so it strip out all the leading space?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a string with multiple white spaces with perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366533/splitting-a-string-with-multiple-white-spaces-with-perl)

Answer (score 2):

If there may or may not be a space, split on `/, ?/` instead of `/, /`.  If there may be any number of spaces, use `/, */`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution with your code (added `\s*` to the second `split`):

```
perl -we '
    my $_ = "station_1:50, station_2:40, station_3:60";
    my %hash = map {split /:/} split /,\s*/;
    use Data::Dumper;
    print Dumper \%hash
'
```

OUTPUT:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'station_1' => '50',
      'station_3' => '60',
      'station_2' => '40'
    };
```

Another working way using regex:

CODE

```
$ echo "station_1:50, station_2:40, station_3:6" |
   perl -MData::Dumper -lne '
        my %h;
        $h{$1} = $2 while /\b(station_\d+):(\d+)/ig;
        print Dumper \%h
'
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
$VAR1 = {
          'station_3' => '6',
          'station_1' => '50',
          'station_2' => '40'
        };
```